# How do I prove that if $rank((T-\lambda I)^m)=rank((T-\lambda I)^{m+1})$ then its kernel is a generalized eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T$ is a linear operator on $V$, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. How do I prove that if $rank((T-\lambda I)^m)=rank((T-\lambda I)^{m+1})$ then $K_\lambda=N((T-\lambda I)^m)$ is a generalized eigenspace of $T$?

Edit: I do know that if $rank(U^m)=rank(U^{m+1})$ then $rank(U^m)=rank(U^{m+n})$ and $N(U^m)=N(U^{m+n})$ for a positive $n$.

Comment: Made an edit, adding something I know